# For...in loop is adding keys instead of values when sending to Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object, which contains some variables and an array. I'm trying to add the data to Firebase. Firebase didn't like the array. My solution was to convert the array to an object and send the object values to an array in Firestore using a For...in loop and a Firestore array query. This almost worked but, for some reason, my code is adding the key names instead of the values, What am I doing wrong?

```
     let projectId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
     let docTitle = this.projectTitle.title;

     this.pages.forEach((page) => {
       let pageT = page.pageTitle;
       let pageD = page.pageDesc;
       let id = page.id;
       let blocks = page.blocks;
       db.collection(docTitle + projectId).doc(pageT).set({
           page: {pageTitle:pageT, pageDesc: pageD, id:id }
         })
         .then(function() {
           console.log("Document successfully written!");
         })
         .catch(function(error) {
           console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
         });


         // Converts array into object and adds object values to an array in firestore

         let newBlocks = Object.assign({}, blocks);
         for(let block in newBlocks){
           db.collection(docTitle + projectId).doc(pageT).update({
             blocks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(block)
           })
         }
     })
```

Here are the Firestore docs on updating arrays: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: `for (..in..)` and `for (..of..)` are different and behave differently. The wrong form (`..in..`, which iterates *keys* including array indices) was probably used. P.S. I find it a bit unfortunate the names are so similar.

Comment: Getting the error: TypeError: newBlocks[Symbol.iterator] is not a function. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: That's a different question / issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use for…of to iterate over the values in an iterable,

Change

```
for(let block in newBlocks){
```

To

```
 for(let block of newBlocks){
```

for...in iterates over object keys hence for...of correct in your case

Comment: Getting the error: TypeError: newBlocks[Symbol.iterator] is not a function. Do you know why that might be? Maybe because my array items are components instead of strings, numbers, booleans etc?

Comment: @GeorgeBleasdale Because newBlocks  is not an array. You don't need it at all. Iterate over blocks variable.